# SQL: How to remove & update records in a table, sync'ing with a (Q)List data in order to decrease the burden on database/table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, qt, qsqlquery

I am using Qt and MS-Sql Server on Windows7 OS.
What I have is an MS-SQL database that I use to store data/info coming from equipment that is mounted in some vehicles.
There is a table in the database named `TransactionFilesInfo` - a table used to store information about transaction files from the equipment, when they connect to the TCP-server.
We are using this table as we are requested to avoid *duplicate* files. It happens (sometimes) when the remote equipment does NOT delete the transaction files after they are sent to the server. Hence, I use the info from the table to check `[size and CRC]` to avoid downloading *duplicates*.
**Some sample data for `TransactionFilesInfo` table looks like this**:

```
[TransactionFilesInfo]:    
DeviceID    FileNo  FileSequence    FileSize    FileCRC  RecordTimeStamp
10203       2       33              230         55384    2015-11-26 14:54:15
10203       7       33              624         55391    2015-11-26 14:54:15
10203       2       34              146         21505    2015-11-26 14:54:16
10203       7       34              312         35269    2015-11-26 14:54:16
10203       2       35              206         23022    2015-11-26 15:33:22
10203       7       35              208         11091    2015-11-26 15:33:22
10203       2       36              134         34918    2015-11-26 15:55:44
10203       7       36              104         63865    2015-11-26 15:55:44
10203       2       37              140         35466    2015-11-26 16:20:38
10203       7       37              208         62907    2015-11-26 16:20:38
10203       2       38              134         17706    2015-11-26 16:38:33
10203       7       38              104         42358    2015-11-26 16:38:33
11511       2       21              194         29913    2015-12-02 16:22:59
11511       7       21              114         30038    2015-12-02 16:22:59
```

On the other hand, every time a device connects to the server, it first sends a list of file information. The Qt application takes care of that.
**The list contains elements like this**:

```
struct FileInfo
{
    unsigned short  FileNumber;
    unsigned short  FileSequence;
    unsigned short  FileCRC;
    unsigned long   FileSize;
};
```

So, as an **example** (inspired by the table above) the connected device (`DeviceID=10203`) may say that it has the following files:

```
QList<FileInfo> filesList;
// here is the log4qt output...
filesList[0] --> FileNo=2 FileSeq=33 FileSize=230 and FileCRC=55384
filesList[1] --> FileNo=2 FileSeq=34 FileSize=146 and FileCRC=21505
filesList[2] --> FileNo=7 FileSeq=33 FileSize=624 and FileCRC=55391 
filesList[3] --> FileNo=7 FileSeq=34 FileSize=312 and FileCRC=35269 ...
```

Well, what I need is a method to remove/delete, for a given `DeviceID`, all the records in the `TransactionFilesInfo` table, records that are NOT in the list sent by the remote device. Hence, I will be able to decrease the burden (size) on the database table.

**Remark**: For the moment I just delete (@midnight) all the records that are older than let's say 10 days, based on `RecordTimeStamp` field. So, the size of the table doesn't increase over an alarming level :)

*Finally, to clarify it a little bit: I would mainly need help with SQL. Yet, I would not refuse any idea on how to do some related things/tricks on the Qt side ;)*

Comment: You have not given enough information to give a complete answer but if you are looking for some SQL you could build to delete those records then it might be like this: `DELETE FROM [SAMPLE DATA] WHERE DeviceID = 10203 and 'File' + CONVERT(varchar(11),FileNo) + '_' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(11),FileSequence),3) NOT IN ('File2_033','File2_034','File7_033','File7_034',...)`

Comment: **What other info should I add in order to provide a complete description?** Your intuition is good: my Qt skills are ok, yet I lack the knowledge of SQL and related stuff... So, yes: your answer is useful. Why did you put it as a comment and not like an answer?! I up-voted it anyway and I'll try to implement your idea in my Qt app tomorrow (I'm not at the office now...).

Comment: I guess I am just unfamiliar with what QT is but is appears to be your development language. It would have been helpful in your question to define what part of this you need help with. IE, DO you need some SQL or some code for parsing the text from your log4qt output and then limit the tags to that. You will get more help if you are more specific. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Answer is simple: I would mainly need help with SQL. Yet I would not refuse any idea on how to do some related things/trick on the Qt side. BTW: Qt is a  cross-platform application framework used for developing application software with GUI (in C++). And... log4qt is just a stupid logger, no need to bother...

Comment: @Steve: Yes, it works! Now the only thing I have to do is to automatically build in Qt that _file_sequence_list_ that will be passed as parameter to `NOT IN(...)`. Doable :)  Hey why don't you formulate it as an answer?

Comment: @Steve: Ok, now I managed to automatically generate the file sequence list in Qt. I tested and it works great! Yet, **there is a circumstance when it crashes**: i.e. when the file sequence list is EMPTY !!! Apparently, `NOT IN()` clause doesn't accept void/empty list... My workaround: I execute the SQL command ONLY if the list is not empty. Is there any other/better approach?

Comment: When the list is empty, I would assume you would want to delete all of them for DeviceID. Just change your SQL in that case to only use the `Where DeviceId = ???` in this case.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was thinking about that, yet - on a second thought - it doesn't worth the effort, as sooner or later the device will show up a list of files anyway :) On the other hand, I decided to keep the clean-up at midnight (delete older records), just to be able to remove "residue", i.e. records belonging to devices that were completely removed from the system, otherwise those records would zombie-ing forever in the database...

Comment: @Steve: StackOverflow keeps pressing me to start a bounty on this, even if you already gave a good solution. So, please take 1 minute to edit an answer (a copy-paste will do). I promise I will accept it. S.O. will be _happy_ and I thank you in advance for that! BR, Stanley G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL to delete those records might look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM [SAMPLE DATA] 
WHERE DeviceID = 10203 
    and 'File' + CONVERT(varchar(11),FileNo) + '_' + 
        RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(11),FileSequence),3) 
        NOT IN ('File2_033','File2_034','File7_033','File7_034',...)
```

If you wanted to delete all of them for a device, you could drop the code that looks at the FileNo and FileSequence so it is simply:

```
DELETE FROM [SAMPLE DATA] 
WHERE DeviceID = 10203
```